# Why does SettinWithCopyError come up when sorting values?

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen this pandas warning many times before and generally understand where this is coming from so normally I don't ever get it but today it suddenly came up in one of the scripts I wrote in the line:

```
points.sort_values(by=['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
```

Here I'm simply sorting the data in a dataframe by values in 3 columns.

I don't understand why this warning is coming up here because to the best of my understanding I'm not doing any chain indexing and explicitly state the I want changes to occur in-place.

Anyone know the reason for the warning here?

Comment: Problem is in code before, how is created `points` ?

Comment: If there is some filtering, need `copy` like `points = df[df['A'] > 10].copy()`